# LabVIEW call DLL with struct return

Tags: struct, dll, labview

I'm create a DLL in C and I trying call the functions to get a struct return value.

If I use a standard variables for function returns (`int`, `float`, `char`, `char*`) works good.

My struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int  success;   /** Success to call a function **/
  char returned[32];  /** Return of the called function **/
} DLL_RETURN_t;
```

Function:

```
DLL_RETURN_t* getData() {
    DLL_RETURN_t* test;
    test->success = 1;
    strcpy((char*)test->returned, "Simple Test");
    return test;
}
```

I use the *Import shared library* LabVIEW tool to import the DLL and create the VIs.

The created VI have a integer output, but I expected a cluster or a pointer.

Comment: The lifetime of the pointer you are returning from you function call is bound to the function so it will not be valid once your function finishes execution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem creating a VI importing a struct from DLL to Labview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378006/problem-creating-a-vi-importing-a-struct-from-dll-to-labview)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the help for **Configuring Return Type**:

> A call to a function in a DLL cannot return a pointer because there are no pointer types in LabVIEW. However, you can specify the return type as an integer that is the same size as the pointer. LabVIEW then treats the address as a simple integer, and you can pass it to future DLL calls

You should be able to use the pointer to get the data in LV, but that's already more complicated and I don't actually remember the details offhand, so you would have to look it up or wait for someone else to fill it in.

What people usually do is to pass a pointer to the struct into the function (in your case it's already there - the first param of **getData()**) and then in LV you can configure that param to be **Adapt to Type** and **Handles by Value**. Pass a cluster into it which matches the struct and you will get the value in the parallel terminal when the node returns. I assume the wizard already did this in your case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is an error in your code: The pointer `test` is declared but never initialized/assigned to, so the dereference is a "read of an uninitialized variable" and therefore undefined behaviour. But I guess this is just due to the simplified example posted here on SO.

So assuming you have a valid pointer in `test` and its lifetime extents beyond the execution of `getData()` your question boils down to

*How do I decode a struct that I have a pointer to?*

The answer to that is by using the function [moveBlock](https://zone.ni.com/reference/de-XX/help/371361R-0113/lvexcode/moveblock/) of the [LabVIEW Manager Functions](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvexcodeconcepts/labview_manager_routines/).

Drop a comment if you are unsure how to use the `moveBlock` function and I will elaborate a bit more on that.